# Parsing JSON file with different number of keys

Tags: android, parsing, arrays, json

My JSON file contains strings with the same keys but some of them doens't appear for some strings. For example:

```
{
    "city": "CB1 2BH Cambridge",
    "addr": "Devonshire Road 1",
    "title": "Devonshire Arms",
    "phone": "+44 1223 6610"
},
{
    "city": "E8 1JH London",
    "addr": "Amhurst Road 90",
    "title": "Pembury Tavern",
    "web": "http://www.individualpubs.co.uk/pembury/"
},
{
    "web": "http://bandholmhotel.dk/",
    "title": "Bandholm Hotel",
},
{
    "city": "00100 Helsinki",
    "addr": "Pohjoinen Rautatiekatu 23",
    "title": "Helkan Baari",
    "country": "FI"
},
```

How to correctly parse it in android?

Answer (score 1):

Considering this is your JSONArray,

Try to do as following,

```
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) jsonProductArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String city = jObj.optString("city", "cityDefaultValue");
    String addr = jObj.optString("addr", "addDefaultValue");
    String title = jObj.optString("title", "titleDefaultValue");
    String phone = jObj.optString("phone", "phoneDefaultValue");
}
```

Comment: In this case how to handle objects that for example don't have "phone" field?

Comment: @smartmouse I have edited my answer as per your requirement, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be to have a modal class and use Gson library to parse the Json.

You can set some default values in your modal class, for keys whose value is not found in Json

Answer (score 0):

Create an model class with the key of the json and parse it to the model class using gson.

```
A a = gson.fromJson(jsonRes.toString(),A.class);
here A is your model class and a is the instance of A
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library.
Create something like that

```
class SomeObjects {
@SerializedName("city")
private String mCity;
@SerializedName("addr")
private String mAddres;
...
}
```

and in then

```
SomeObject obj = new Gson.fromJson(jsonString, SomeObject.class);
```

You also can sirialize right into array